# Hide command execution detection in ps

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sh

I have a bash script with contents-

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;do
netstat -antp | grep LISTEN | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 > /tmp/log
sleep 100
done
```

Say I create a service which executes the script on boot.But when I use `ps -eo command` I'm able to see the commands being executed.For eg -

```
netstat -antp
grep LISTEN
tr -s ' '
cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

But I wish to suppress this output and hide the execution of these commands.Is there a way to do it?

Any other suggestions are welcome too.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Easiest way I can think of, make a C++ equivalent, compile it and put it some non suspicious name. Problem solved

Comment: IMHO, this would be more on topic on Unix&Linux or SuperUser. But hopefully you cannot hide execution of a command from the system and its administrators...

Comment: I'm not able to find the equivalent commands to do that. I tried using the system() function but encountered the same problem.

Comment: If you only want to hide the names of the commands, just make local copies and rename them. But this would be a serious attack and **you** will have to face the consequences when caught. Admins are often less stupids that users imagine...

Comment: That won't be a problem it's for a CTF(catch the flag) game.Even the renaming thing could funny, I mean it can be investigated.Can I create a binary with the commands so that just the execution of the binary shows up?

Comment: `ln grep foobar`; `ln tr bazqux`; `ln cut something`; `ln netstat whatever`, and then `whatever -antp | foobar LISTEN | bazqux -s ' ' | something -d ' ' -f 4`. Of course, you could also write the whole thing as an AWK script -- if the script comes from a file, much easier to obscure, and you don't need `grep`/`tr`/`cut` at all.

Comment: ...really, you could avoid those using bash-builtin string manipulation anyhow.

Comment: ...but as dbush has said, many of us prefer not to help people do obviously-malicious things (or things that, generally, have more malicious uses than legitimate ones).

Comment: ...no, you can't create a binary **with the commands** unless you put the implementation of the commands inside the binary. That said, you might look at busybox -- as a multi-call executable, it *is*, itself, a binary that has all the separate commands involved here built in.

Comment: As I've said it's for a CTF and no malicious purpose. I think using awk is a good idea too, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide running processes from the system, at least not without some kernel hooks.  Doing so is something typically only found in malware, so you'll not likely get much help.

There's really no reason to hide those processes from the system.  If something in your script gets hung up, you'll want to see those processes to give you an idea of what's happening.

If there's a specific problem the presence of those processes is causing, you need to detail what that is.

Comment: Just wish to make the script undetectable so that players can't find about it in a CTF. I'm running it as root ,is there at least a way to hide it from non root users?

Comment: @ShakshamJaiswal, is there a way? Sure, you could create a different process namespace and ensure that whatever daemon (sshd or whatever) the players connect to are inside it. But if this is a CTF, folks may be wise to that. Anyhow, if you want whole-system monitoring, this is both a really expensive approach in terms of performance and also not so great in terms of coverage; I'd go with something kernel-based, such as [Sysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/). Even then, you'll want something like aformentioned namespace-based separation to hide its userspace components.

Comment: ...sysdig will also get you a much more comprehensive recording of what's going on inside the machine, if that's something you actually want. (That said, if you **really** want to be safe, do the monitoring from outside -- ie. run the game on a virtual machine, and store a pcap of all the traffic in and out, captured from equipment that isn't fair-game).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll surely look into it.